# How to change part of the url every 5 seconds

Tags: javascript

I need to change part of URL every 5 seconds and refresh the browser tab with a new URL

URL: looks like

https://tes.test/tes/test#12.4/40.0000/-0.0/24.934764/55.158747/22981.332850

And I want to change for example /40.000/ every 5 seconds by adding 5k (40.000+5.000=new URL with 45.000 every 5 seconds.

I have doubt that this can be done with `windows.location` but I have no idea how to implement this.

For now, I have

```
cy.get('canvas').click()
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
    let url = window.location.href
    const refreshData = url.split("/")[5]
    url = url.replace(refreshData, `${+refreshData + 5}`)
    console.log(url)
    cy.visit(url)
    cy.wait(1000)
```

but this is not updating URL in Cypress browser tab

Comment: `window.location.hash.split("/");`

Comment: What have you tried?  You seem to know that you can access the current URL with `window.location` already and then it's just a matter of parsing it, modifying it and setting the new URL.  What part of that do you need help with?

Comment: @jfriend00 I have this part of code but It does not open a new URL. cy.get('canvas').click()
    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++){
        let url = window.location.href
        const refreshData = url.split("/")[5]
        url = url.replace(refreshData, `${+refreshData + 5}`)
        console.log(url)
        cy.visit(url)
        cy.wait(1000)

Comment: @jfriend00 edited qustion. sorry for missing more info here

Comment: And, what part of that is not working?  What result do you get?  What result do you want that is different from that?  When I run your code on iteration on that URL, I get: `https://tes.test/tes/test#12.4/45/-0.0/24.934764/55.158747/22981.332850` which is as expected.